# Java abstract class to get type of extended class

Tags: java

I don't how to phrase this, so I'll drop an example

```
class AbstractUser<A extends AbstractAccount<? extends AbstractType>> {
    // I want a method that has access to Type
    // And returns the specific Type that extends AbstractType
    protected <T extends AbstractType> T doSomething(T type) {
        // do stuff
        // and return the type specific type T
    }
}

class AbstractAccount<T extends AbstractType> {

}

class AbstractType {

}


class Type extends AbstractType {

}

class Account extends AbstractAccount<Type> {

}

class AccountAdmin extends AbstractAccount<Type> {

}

class User extends AbstractUser<Account> {

}
```

What I want in this is that within `User` class I can do `getType()` and it returns the the specific type of `AbstractAccount`, in this case `Account`.

How do I do this without specifying any more templates? In other words, I want whatever type the `?` in `? extends AbstractType` is to be in that method

So if I do

```
final Account account = ...
final AccountAdmin admin = ...
final User user = ...
user.doSomething(account); // should work
user.doSomething(AccountAdmin); // should fail
```

Comment: _'in this case Account'_ Is the return type should same as Class in angular AbstractUser<Account>??

Comment: @Tarun there can be many types of `AbstractAccount`, let's say `AccountAdmin`, `AccountDeveloper` etc

Comment: Something like `this.getClass().getName()` might do what you want.

Comment: @dave Not at all. That is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Java 8 you could define a constructor which takes a `Supplier` returning instances of the appropriate type.

You said:
*What I want in this is that within User class I can do getType() and it returns the the specific type of AbstractAccount, in this case Account.*

And you want: `doSomething(T type)`.
Thus I assume, you don't want a `Class<T>` but an instance of `T` to work with. As of your example this `T` should be `Account`.

According to this:

```
class AbstractUser<T extends AbstractType, A extends AbstractAccount<T>> {

    private Supplier<T> accountSupplier;

    public AbstractUser(Supplier<T> accountSupplier) {
        this.accountSupplier = accountSupplier;
    }

    protected T getType() {
        return accountSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

Then class `User` would look as follows:

```
class User extends AbstractUser<Type, Account> {

    public User() {
        super(Account::new);
    }
}
```

Please note that the class `AbstractUser` is still not declared `abstract`. If the only reason to have this class is providing different types of `AbstractAccount` by subclasses, then now we can do it without subclasses.

`User user = new User();` can be rewritten as `AbstractUser user = new AbstractUser(Type::new);` <sub>(in this case `AbstractUser` is not the best name)</sub>.

Answer (score 4):

You obviously can't create a method in `AbstractUser` like this:

```
public Class<A> getType() { return A.class; }
```

This is because of type erasure. The runtime does not know what `A` is.

So one workaround is to make this method abstract:

```
public abstract Class<A> getType();
```

Now, you can implement this method in subclasses:

```
class User extends AbstractUser<Account> {
    public Class<Account> getType() { return Account.class; }
}
```

EDIT:

Now I realised you want the type that extends `AbstractType`, the workaround should still work. You just need to create another `getType` in `AbstractAccount` and make `Account` implement that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really get around binding another type parameter in `AbstractUser` for this purpose:

```
class AbstractUser<T extends AbstractType, A extends AbstractAccount<T>> {
    protected abstract T getType();
}
```

You need a way to reference the type of A's type parameter, and this serves that purpose.

Comment: That means I'd need to do `class User extends AbstractUser< Type, Account>` then? But `Account` already has template `Type` :( seems like repetition

Comment: @Kousha: It is repetition in the sense that an infinitely flexible type system would be able to refer to the instantiation of `T` in `A` with some syntax (e.g. `T of A extends AccountType<T>`) but it's not harmful in that your need of knowing this type in `AbstractUser` indicates two separate dependencies: one on the account type and one on the account itself.

Comment: Alright, this will be problematic for my need cause there are tons of implementations of `AbstractUser` so changing that means I have to do edit a lot files.

Comment: @Kousha: Lean on the IDE where possible I guess, and note that you can have intermediate abstract classes that specify the type parameter, so e.g. `User` extends `IntermediateAbstractUser<Account>` extends `AbstractUser<Type, A>`  Might be less that needs to change.

Comment: Minor hint only for the sake of completness: `abstract class AbstractUser` since there is the abstract method `getType()`.